# Smartcontract: Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [Reverted]

Tags: error

I have sent ETH to a contract address, and it "failed" the transaction saying it is: Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [Reverted]

contract address and transaction failure here:
https://etherscan.io/tx/0xa790149d714d614601ded9df1ad40b3830953b5a019b4ea9030cd1699344f2acE

can someone help and explain please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the correct transaction is this one: https://etherscan.io/tx/0xa790149d714d614601ded9df1ad40b3830953b5a019b4ea9030cd1699344f2ac. (You had an extra character at the end.)

The contract code is here: https://etherscan.io/address/0x73de68d64b5d9b2108fdf76a394f76e16a88ceb3#code. Because no `data` field was specified, your transaction invoked the fallback function, which in turn calls `getTokens`:

```
function getTokens() payable canDistr  public {
```

Note the `canDistr` modifier, which is defined this way:

```
modifier canDistr() {
    require(!distributionFinished);
    _;
}
```

As you can see [here](https://etherscan.io/address/0x73de68d64b5d9b2108fdf76a394f76e16a88ceb3#readContract), `distributionFinished` is `true`, so the `require` statement reverted the transaction.

Comment: This isn't something that can be "fixed". The contract has a few different ways to set `distributionFinished = true`, all of which imply that the contract will no longer be distributing any more tokens. Seems like you are just too late to the party.